# Git/GitHub Total Number Of Lines Contributed For An Account

Tags: git, github, lines-of-code

I want to get the total number of lines of code that an account on GitHub has done. This is not for judging productivity or whatever (LOC is a poor choice for that), it's really just for our amusement.

Is it possible to get the total number of lines of code that an Account on GitHub (by email address or handle) has done?

Comment: The most direct solution would be to write a script that uses the GitHub API to locally clone all your repos and run [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) for that:

- Use [/user/:user/repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) to get all repositories
- Then use [/repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts) to get the contributors (and their additions / deletions) on those repositories

Comment: `/user/:user/repos` does not list repositories to which user has contributed but is not an owner or member of (but has made pull requests).